# Does there exist an infinite solvable group with no normal abelian subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, solvable-groups

This is impossible if $G$ is finite and solvable, because then $G$ has a (nontrivial) minimal normal subgroup $A$, which can be shown (using a trick) to be abelian.

I'm trying to mimic the same proof when $G$ is infinite and solvable, but there it's not obvious (to me at least) that $G$ must have a minimal normal subgroup. Any ideas?

Comment: Infinite solvable groups don't have to have minimal normal subgroups, (take $\mathbb{Z}$, for example), but when they do, the minimal normal subgroups are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: The derived subgroups are characteristic, hence normal; if the $n$-th derived subgroup is $\{1\}$ and $G^{(n-1)}\ne\{1\}$, then $G^{(n-1)}$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.